# Improper use of quote marks and straw man logical fallacies

Tags: discussion

This is a request for quote marks to be used solely for their original purpose, that is to quote **verbatim** a statement made in a post. They should not to be used as part of a logical fallacy /straw man argument. This has happened to me twice in  two days by users with undoubtedly the best of motives.

But by basing your argument or point on a personal interpretation or summing up  rather than the **actual** statement made  is completely unfair, imo and is compounded by a lack of courtesy/respect in not acknowledging the fact of improper attribution.

I would ask users not to write a comment, altering the words in someone's else's post,  leave a set of quotes around it, along with an implication based on the altered version and then dissappear, leaving the original poster frustrated by a lack of a response after fruitlessly looking to edit a statement that was never made.

Comment: I would guess you're referring to [comments like this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278657/visualizing-a-light-wave/278659#comment625441_278659), though this doesn't seem terribly offensive. From a quick look through your recent posts I couldn't see any other examples - perhaps you could clarify your question by including some examples.

Comment: @JohnRennie no, its not offensive at all , it's obviously  meant sincerely and is motivated by enthusiasm and a never give up attitude which  I admire .  But its also just plain wrong: 1. In its quote which I  never said 2. In its implications which are the reverse of my post, 3. In its lack of respect in not bothering to respond, but most importantly of all by far 4. In the impression it may leave an OP, especially a newbie, by summing up someone else's  argument (incorrectly) in a soundbite style. It's not something I would do. Its just bad practice, more than any personal thing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure we need a meta post to comment on the failures of a few users' communication skills. People misuse quotes all the time. Why not comment to those users specifically and help them improve? We don't need a meta post unless the problem is systemic.

Comment: I just think that as the issue of people misusing quotes is neither unique to this site nor a major problem on this site (as far as I know), there's no point in a meta post.

Comment: @DanielSank your point is taken and I have VTC my question. In my day job, if I misquoted a source, I would have a lot of explaining to do. I can see that this site has no need, as it is not a commercial enterprise, to alter it's current policy.  Thank you for taking the time to clarify that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's both impossible and undesirable to police people's writing styles. Who's going to be on the Commitee For Proper Use Of Quotation Marks (CFPUOQM)? How will they enfore the restrictions? Why can't you just point the error out to the person using quotation marks "wrongly" like one would with any other error?

If you think there is a *significant pattern* of multiple people using quotation marks improperly, consider that your idea of how quotation marks should be used might be overly narrow and not shared by the general population. In particular, I see *no issue* with putting a paraphrase in quotation marks - yes, if the paraphrase is inaccurate, this is building a strawman, but *not using quotation marks* wouldn't have changed that being a fallacy, would it? Unless the quotation marks are accompanied by an explicit "You said that:", I don't think that such marks always imply a verbatim quote.

If people are misunderstanding you and putting words in your mouth, the problem isn't that they are using quotation marks to do so, it's that they *misunderstood what you were trying to say*! You're trying to solve this communication problem from entirely the wrong angle, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for a considered response, and yes, it just goes to prove that there are indeed wiser people than I on this site.  I suppose my point was that on a lot of sites  similar to this one,  if you removed the  ad hominem and  straw man arguments, you would  be left with very little actual content. After the work that has been put to maintain the standards of this site, I would not like to see that happen here. Your last paragraph, I just can't argue with, you are correct. So I will vote to close. Thank you.